# Emission + Transmission not Working

Tags: eevee-render-engine, emission

I'm working on a pickup truck. I have ELS on it, but I can't get the visor lights to shine as brightly as the others. The window tint also distorts their color. Any known fixes for either the bloom or the color?

Edit:

- Yes, ELS stands for emergency lighting system.
- Yes, I meant to show the glass material,  not the lights.

Contact be via Discord (truk3232) if you wish to speak with me about this issue.

[image: distorted amber lights]
[image: blue lights]
[image: glass nodes]

Comment: What does ELS mean?

Comment: probably Emergency Lighting System? What does it give if you plug the ColorRamp into an Emission shader (or into the Emission input of the Principled BSDF)? I'm not even sure how they can bloom right now as there is no emission...

Comment: @moonboots The material is called "010 glass" and has a _Transmission_ value of 1. It's the windscreen, I guess - not the lights.

Comment: Oh OK, so I guess his problem is that the light behind the glass is not strong enough

Comment: For the question about _Bloom_: you will not get more than a small amount of bloom on emissive objects that are behind transmissive objects in _Eevee_, even if you set the _Treshold_ to 0 and the _Emission Strength_ to 50.000, if you want more then you have to use the _Compositor_. @moonboots it will never be enough with _Eevee_ ;)

Comment: OK, i didn't remember that;)

Comment: You use the term ELS. Are you concerned about how this object will render in GTA? Is the Blender render a reliable indicator of that? (This may not be a Blender question)